# php sql - match a set of numbers with another set

Tags: php, sql

I have a set of numbers (lets say around 120-150 ) in a table and i have another table in my database which stores the country code and the respective calling pins .

Now country pins can vary from 1-4 digits and i have to match the set of numbers with the country pins to get the country codes from the database .

I have tried the below but to no avail as the country codes can vary from 1 to 4 digits .

```
$subject = "211";
$pattern = '/^211/';
preg_match($pattern, $subject, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE, 3);
```

Can someone please help me figure out a way to go about it.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: I am sorry but i dont get what you didn't get . I have 100 numbers against which i need to match the calling pin numbers (length from 1 to 4) .

Answer (score -1):

for loop up to  set of number , then then take one by one and check in sql query,

```
select * from table where countrypin like %SETOFNUMBER%
```

If u get output then find `countrycode` from it.

Comment: say i have 3 numbers for Eg : 21333333 , 21234567 , 2156789 
and lets say the calling pins are as below : 
Country 1 : 21 
Country 2 : 212
Country 3 : 213
As per your logic , if i loop the first number which is 21333333 ,it will show me all the three countries which it shouldn't .It should output Country 3 for the first number . Hope i am clear.

Comment: of all the 'great' programmers here seems like no one could make head or tail of how to go about it..great..!!